# press back button on navigation bar multiple times to go back

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android application, but it has an issue. When I click on any menu a single time and press back button it works fine, but If I press particular menu 5-6 times, the back button won't work for a single click.

I have to press back button 5-6 times. I mean when I click menu twice, I have to press back button twice to go back.

Comment: post some code so we can help u

Comment: you need do workground by your self. if you are using fragment clear back stack when clicking on menu.. if you are using activities then clear all top activities

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you